# Powershell: Pipe filename with specials chars to del fails

Tags: powershell, pipe, special-characters

I'm trying to delete duplicate images by checking the hash, and I found this great one line of code to use, but I'm having problems with it.

```
ls $folder\*.* -recurse  | get-filehash | group -property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group | select -skip 1 } | del
```

Spaced Out Code

```
ls $folder\*.* -recurse  |
get-filehash |
group -property hash |
where { $_.count -gt 1 } |
% { $_.group | select -skip 1 } |
del
```

If a file name contains "[" or "]" the image is not deleted.
I know you can do -LiteralPath with del, but that requires a string after it and I'm not sure how to get that working with pipes.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your actual problem, but to use `-LiteralPath` from a pipe: `| % { del -LiteralPath $_.FullName }`

Comment: No I just get Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LiteralPath' because it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that it'd been passed through Get-FileHash and Group-Object.  Try this:

```
ls $folder\*.* -recurse  |
get-filehash |
group -property hash |
where { $_.count -gt 1 } |
% { $_.group | 
    select -skip 1 | 
    % { 
        del -LiteralPath $_.Path
    } 
}
```

This is a bit weird because it's going to be fairly arbitrary about which file it keeps and which file it deletes, but technically this should work.